# Ruby on Rails testing: How can I test or at the very least see a form_for's error_messages_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, functional-testing, form-for, error-messages-for

I'm working on creating a tests, and I can't figure out why the creation of a model from a form_for is failing in the test but works in real browsers.  Is there a straightforward way for me to see what the problems are in the model creation?

Even better would be, is there a straightforward way for me to test the error outputs that I access via error_messages_for?  In that case, I'd like to also add in tests that make sure that malformed forms are outputting the correct errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the validation errors on an object using `@model.errors`. Use `@model.errors.on(:field_name)` to get an array of error messages applied to a particular field. You can also use `@model.errors.invalid?(:field_name)` in your tests to assert that an error was triggered for a particular field.

For example:

```
test "should reject invalid post" do
  @p = Post.new
  assert !@p.valid?
  assert_equal @p.errors.on(:title), 'cannot be blank'
end
```